# Eclipse is not working properly

Tags: eclipse

I clicked on eclipse and I got this error:

> Failed to load JNI Library "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll"

The java version is up to date and the path is correct. I'm not sure how to fix this. I'm using Eclipse IDE Java Developer

Comment: [Better place](http://superuser.com/) to ask this question.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether your eclipse and java are of the same version i.e both 32bit or both 64 bit.

You can try on the command line:

`java -d64 -version`

If it's not a 64-bit version, you'll get a message that looks like:

`This Java instance does not support a 64-bit JVM. Please install the desired version.`

To check eclipse :

Open `eclipse.ini` file and observe the following 4th line

plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.0.200.v20090519

This shows eclipse is 32 bit

Comment: plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130521-0416 This one?

Comment: and Java  -d64 -version yep.

Comment: If you have TeamViewer 8 or Skype I can share my screens and you can help me to

Comment: can you post your results of java as well as eclipse :)

Comment: your eclipse is 32 bit and java is 64 bit , you either need to get 32bit java or 64 bit eclipse

Comment: I just reintalled it still the same :L

Answer (score 1):

I think you may not have downloaded and installed JNI(Java Native Interface). by the looks of it you have the JRE(Java Runtime Environment) and that's where the path is set. Try downloading Java Native Interface and set path to that. Just an idea

Comment: Ok I downloaded JNI now what do I do

Comment: go to the start menu, right click on computer and click properties. then click advanced system settings. Click on environment variables. find PATH and set it to the location at which your JNI is downloaded, i think this would work. i have eclipse classic, but seeing from the error, i think it's because of JNI. so yeah, set the path to the location where JNI is saved, then i think it would work.